# Video tag in electron

Tags: html, video, electron

I'm trying to play videos (mp4) in an window loaded with Electron.
Weird thing : it works fine with only one video, with the others it shows a black screen. The only difference between all videos are their width and height (does that matter ?). Also, in a browser window all videos play just fine.

Here's the code that load windows in electron :

```
let mainWindow;
let playerWindow;


app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('ready', function() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  title: 'MasterGameApp',
  x: 910,
  y: 500,
  width: 800,
  height: 460,
  show: true,
  resizable: false,
  transparent: false
});

playerWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  title: 'playerView',
  x: 2250,
  y: 50,
  width: 1005,
  height: 540,
  show: true,
  transparent: false,
  fullscreen : true
});

mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8889');
mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false);
mainWindow.setAutoHideMenuBar(true);
playerWindow.loadUrl('http://localhost:8889/playerView');
playerWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false);
playerWindow.setAutoHideMenuBar(true);

mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
  playerWindow.close();
  playerWindow = null;
  mainWindow = null;
});
});
```

The videos url are simply given to a video tag inside a JS script like this `$('#someDiv').append('<video id=\'backgroundvid\' autoplay><source src=\''+ content +'\' type=\'video/mp4\'></video>');`

I don't understand why the browser can play every video but the electron window can't ... Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ummm hey. I just saw the beginning of your URL property for the video tag is out of the inverted commas.
What you have:

```
$('#someDiv').append('<video id=\'backgroundvid\' autoplay><source src=\''+ content +'\' type=\'video/mp4\'></video>');
```

What you should have:

```
$('#someDiv').append('<video id=\'backgroundvid\' autoplay><source src=&quot;\''+ content +'\' type=\'video/mp4\'&quot;></video>');
```

Have you tried changing that?
Stay lit; keep doing Electron. I am a great fan of it and can see its potential for future desktop applications.

NOTE: Also, I am not sure what your CORS settings are or anything, but if it it trying to load videos locally, it may not let you.

Comment: Thank's for the answer, but this is not the problem, commas are fine (just did some tests), this code works great with one video (and all videos in a browser), but shows a blackscreen with others video (in electron window).
And I agree, Electron is pretty cool, and also easy to start with

Comment: Ok, so I just converted the files with proper height and width and that did the job ...

Comment: @LongDuZboub If that fixed it, can you self-answer, then mark it as correct? (If you've worked out why there is a height/width restriction, that'd be good to put in your answer too!)

Comment: Ah ok... The problem probably lied in the way Electon was made... Even though it is based off the Chromium browser, they probably changed a couple of things when handling videos.