# Playing videos in electron

Tags: html, video, electron, desktop-application, mp4

I'm currently writing an electron application to run as a desktop app on Windows.
I'm trying to embed a video on the page to all the end user to play it and it appear impossible.

Sample code is:

```
 <video  controls="">
    <source src="../../../2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

I have checked and tried the following solutions and a few others:

- [Cannot play offline video in production electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565472/cannot-play-offline-video-in-production-electron-app)
- [Video tag in electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708165/video-tag-in-electron)
- [Electron video cannot play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55074055/electron-video-cannot-play)
- [Playing local mp4 file in electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554249/playing-local-mp4-file-in-electron)

And I've unfortunately had no success.

Thanks in advance for any help or support.

Regards

Patrick

Comment: Electron can definitely play embedded videos from the local filesystem within the render process, you don't need videojs. It should be able to play anything that Chromium can play, I have gotten this working in my Electron (v20.3+) project. That said, there are a number of barriers such as videos with unsupported codecs, and webSecurity settings. 

For websecurity issues, I was most helped by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66673831

For codec issues, you may want to make sure your video isn't H264 or some other unsupported codec. You can transcode with ffmpeg if that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution here was to use the node-cmd module and pass the file path to the command prompt which opens the file in the OS' default program.

Code:

```
const cmd = require("node-cmd")
cmd.runSync("/your/file/path/video.mp4")
```

Comment: Not ideal and not what I was looking for but a suitable compromise for now.

Answer (score 0):

use the https://github.com/videojs/video.js to play videos.

Electron or nodejs provides the access to local files.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30583761)